# Why total positive bound charges of polar dielectric exist only on surface and negative charges in volume when exposed to external electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, polarization, dielectric

[image: source: Principles of Electromagentics, 6 th edition, Matthew N O Sadiku, S V Kulkarni]

The above image describes the potential due to Polar dielectric material when placed in an external electric field.
In that I don't understand why only total bound positive charge exists on the surface and negative bound charges in the volume? 
According to my intuition, a polar molecule has dipole aligned in the direction of electric field and this exists throughout the volume, hence both positive and negative charges in the volume. But on the surface( if rectangular) the surfaces parallel to electric field will have opposite charges.

[image]

This is how I am imagining.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: I also don't understand the text book. Your drawing is correct.

Comment: Oh...yes sir, book hasn't provided clear explanation of it.